# Flutter: Quickaction

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, user-experience

I would like to implement the Quickstart model that I found in: [Material design](https://material.io/design/communication/onboarding.html#quickstart-model). Does anything like this exist in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `ListView()` with `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` to achieve the horizontal Scroll and as `children: <Widget> [...]` your desired Widget with your desired action, like in your example, to select something.

See this example here of a horizontal ListView: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/horizontal-list

If you only want to show this screen on the first time starting up the App you can simply store, that it was viewed, on the device locally. And decide which screen you want to show in the startup.